# Date Transformation Issues

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are doing the below date conversions on our data transforming a datetime to date and seeing the following error on the 2nd entry.  The date value has decreased by 1 day.

Code:
SELECT ID, CASENUMBER, CREATEDDATE, CAST(CREATEDDATE AS DATE), TO_DATE(CREATEDDATE) AS NEW_DATE
FROM CASE_1
WHERE CASENUMBER IN ('05615406','05615903');

Output:
[image: ID CASENUMBER CREATEDDATE DATE1 DATE2 5001L00001nY7SaQAK 05615903 2020-07-16 13:44:24 2020-07-16 2020-07-16 5001L00001nY5pAQAS 05615406 2020-07-16 01:59:40 2020-07-15 2020-07-15]

Comment: It's hard to see what the date values are; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good question. Can you please update your post with the actual values of `CREATEDDATE`?

Comment: I suspect this is a timezone issue. Can you please let us know: 
- Which Snowflake region is this on?
- What column type is CREATEDDATE (is it just a varchar)?